# How to add `charset=utf-8` to responses matching given content-type criteria in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring

I have a requiremet to add `charset=utf-8` to "all responses" except responses of given content type. So for example, response having `application/json` or `application/xml` should have appended charset but `application/pdf` or `application/zip` and eg `octet-stream` should not. I have tried to use filter to do that, however response's `content-type` is not yet set, thus I cannot introspect it.

This does not work as content type is always `null`

```
@Bean
public CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter() {
    CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter() {
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            String contentType = response.getContentType();
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(contentType)) {
                //add other conditions if needed
                if (!contentType.contains(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE) && !contentType.contains("stream")) {
                    response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    };
    return filter;
}
```

PS

normally, I would just add properties

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.force-response=true
```

but that will append to every response and having charset specified does not make sense for streams, pdfs and zips - thus the criteria matching requirement.

Do I have to wrap response into proxy object like in servlet filters?

Comment: An MVC interceptor might do it, but there may be a cleaner way.